# Showing the local date on input value

Tags: html, date

Good morning guys ! I have a quick question to ask, I have a form on my HTML page, and I want to show the local date in value of the input 'Insertion date'.
This is my code and it isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    Insertion date: <input type="date" id="date">

        <script>
    document.getElementById("dateinsertion").innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you can set a default date and set it to the user system time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element id is not correct use 'date' instead of 'dateinsertion', and then use the following code to initial it.

```
document.getElementById("date").valueAsDate = new Date();
```

Comment: it works ! thank you.
And even when I change the id="date" and I keep :
document.getElementById("dateinsertion").innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
it doesn't work

Comment: It will not work because there is no element with id of ’dateinsertion’, the id you’ve set is id=‘date’. The text box is also of type date so it will not accept string as value, and by the way set the value of any given text box through its value attribute. In our case we use valueAsDate because this is of type date.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `<input id="datetime" type="datetime-local">`

The only problem with standard HTML datepicker is that it doesn't work in Firefox.

If you want it to work in Firefox, take a look at: Bootstrap datepicker.
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/